# Divisors split into a sections

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose we have family $(\pi:U \longrightarrow X), \{p_i\},f)$ be in $\overline{M}_{g,n}(P^r,d).$ I want to know what does the following statement mean:

the cartier divisors $f^\ast{t_i}$ split into sections $\{q_i,_j\}$

We have $f:U\longrightarrow P^r$. I think it means that when we look at a fibre of $x$ which is a stable curve then zero scheme of$f^\ast{t_i}$ as a cartier divisor is $\{q_{i,1}(x)\} +\{q_{i,2}(x)\} +\cdots +\{q_{i,d}(x)\}$.

$t_0$,$t_1$,...,$t_r$ is basis for $H^0(P^r,O(1))$.

Am i right?

Comment: If you're doing this kind of math you should learn LaTeX, and the code used in MathJax is mostly (not entirely) the same as what is done in LateX (albeit far less elaborate). Thus a thing like $$(\pi:U \longrightarrow X), \{p_i\},f)$$ should be between just ONE pair of dollar signs or ONE pair of double dollar signs rather than several, and rather than entirely excluding some parts of it from MathJax, as you did. And something like $q_{i,2}$ should not be coded as q_i,_2 but as q_{i,2}. Note that they look different: $q_{i,2}$ versus $q_i,_2. \qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$and something like $P^r$ should also be between only ONE pair of dollar signs. $\qquad$

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? Are the $t_i$ the images of the marked points on your stable curve?

Comment: Sorry you are right.$t_0$,$t_1$,...,$t_r$ is basis for $H^0(P^r,O(1))$.

Comment: It means essentially that. If $\pi\colon C\to S$ is a smooth separated finitely presented morphism of relative dimension $1$, then any section $s$ of $\pi$ defines a relative effective Cartier divisor in $C$ over $S$. Now, if you have an arbitrary relative effective Cartier divisor on $C$ over $S$, you can ask whether it is a linear combination of sections of $\pi$, in which case one might call it _split_. See e.g. Chapter 1 of Katz–Mazur for more on relative divisors.